# Tomcat error on deploying war file

Tags: tomcat

I am trying to deploy a web app on tomcat 7 and see this error and nothing else
how do i fix this?

```
    INFO: Deploying web application archive xyz.war 
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
    Cannot start daemon 
    Service exit with a return value of 5
```

Comment: Is that all that's in the actual log files?

Answer (score 0):

There is some extra context tags in server.xml which not properly closed

Comment: I dont have any context tags defined

Comment: sorry i cannot, anything i can answer specifically or increase the logging somehow? Thanks a lot!